# Change random result to sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change this random result into a sequence starting from lower number? I am new in JS and have tried to make modification with no solution. I hope anybody can help.

```
function randomFeed() {
    var $el = $("#randomFeed");

 var random = new Array('news1','news2','news3','news4','news5','news6');

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var newElement = random[randomIndex];

        $el.prepend("<tr><td>" + newElement + "</td></tr>").find("tr").first().hide();
        $el.find("tr").first().fadeIn();
        if ($el.find("tbody tr").length > 20) {
            $el.find("tbody tr").last().fadeOut(400, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }

    slimScrollUpdate($el.parents(".scrollable"));

    setTimeout(function() {
        randomFeed();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: rip out the random stuff, and just make "randomIndex" an incrementing counter variable. e.g. `var notsorandomIndex = 0;` then `notsorandomIndex++` somewhere.

Comment: What is your goal? What do you mean by 'How to change this random result into a sequence starting from lower number'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need sequential news slide instead of random? Try this (note the global `feedIndex` variable)

```
var feedIndex = 0;

function randomFeed() {
    var $el = $("#randomFeed"),
        news = new Array('news1','news2','news3','news4','news5','news6'),
        newElement = news[feedIndex++ % news.length];

    //console.log(newElement);

    $el.prepend("<tr><td>" + newElement + "</td></tr>").find("tr").first().hide();
    $el.find("tr").first().fadeIn();
    if ($el.find("tbody tr").length > 20) {
        $el.find("tbody tr").last().fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }

    slimScrollUpdate($el.parents(".scrollable"));

    setTimeout(function() {
        randomFeed();
    }, 3000);
}
```

BTW, this code in it's state is very bad. It changes the DOM every time to show new feed element. It is better to render all elements whith `display:none` and only toggle visibility of actual one. It is common pattern

Comment: by trying yours I got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
news = new Array('news1','news2','news3','news4','news5','news6')

// option 1
news.sort(function() {
      return .5 - Math.random();
    });
//news = news1,news2,news3,news6,news4,news5

//option 2
len = news.length,
randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * len) + 0);
// randomNumber = 3

part = news.slice(randomNumber, len)
// part = arrnews6,news4,news5
```

Please be more precise what are you expecting/about what your goal is!

Comment: can you write more script where to put that. Really I have less knowledge of JS. I have tried yours but remain fail. Must learn more from you.